# Python-PANDAS dataframe- Datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, strftime

I am trying to get a specific format i.e. date-month-year eg: 01-12-2023 12:00:00;00 AM.
In my dataframe i have a column which is in a  datetime format i.e. 2023-12-01.
Here i tried to convert the datetime format into the format that i needed by using strftime ,however didnt want the datatype to be changed so  after converting using strftime , converted back again in datetime.
After doing so , again it went back datetime format i.e. 2023-12-01 instead of 01-12-2023 12:00:00;00 AM.
How can i  resolve this by getting the required format and not changing the datatype.
Checked few examples but didnt work.

Code:

```
Below code creates a new column DOB1   from the Month column which has a datetime format :

Dataframe bkp:

Month 
2022-05-01
2023-06-01

bkp['DOB1'] = bkp['Month'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y  %I:%M:%S %p')

Output:

Month          DOB1
2022-05-01     01-05-2022 12:00:00:00 AM
2023-06-01     01-06-2023 12:00:00:00 AM

bkp.dtypes >>>> Month : datetime64[ns] , DOB1 : object

# Converting to datetime format , to retain the original format

bkp['DOB1'] = pd.to_datetime(bkp['DOB1'])

Output:

Month          DOB1
2022-05-01     2022-05-01
2023-06-01     2023-06-01
```

Could anyone suggest how to get the required format and have the datetime format still.

Comment: This is not directly possible, either keep the original format or use a string

Comment: What you actually want is to change the `pandas` default datetime showing format, so you can preserve your columns as a `datetime` type, while still being able to get it printed in the "day-month-year" format.

Comment: Is it possible to get 01-05-2022 12:00:00:00 AM this format directly in datetime if not converting in string? datatype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: Is it possible to get 01-05-2022 12:00:00:00 AM this format directly in datetime if not converting in string? datatype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: No. Datetime as a data type has no *format*. The format is what you get if you convert to string.